# Proper way of doing the systematic computations / initializations at the beginning of a program

Tags: fortran

I am writing a program that I will use in two main cases: 1D and 2D. The dimension `ndim` is loaded through a `read` of an external file, this `read` I want to do in module `param`.

I have various declarations of vectors whose sizes depend on the dimension. So obviously I have to compute these sizes at the beginning of my main program. What is the proper way of doing so? I want to use a module but I fail.

```
module dimensions
  use prec
  use param
  implicit none
  integer ( int32 ), parameter :: nip = 49   ! Number of interior points
contains
subroutine calc_neqn ( )
  use prec
  implicit none
  integer ( int32 ) :: nup                   ! Number of unknown points
  integer ( int32 ) :: neqn                  ! Number of equations

! compute number of unknown points
  nup = (nip+2)**ndim
! compute number of equations
  neqn = 2*nup

end subroutine calc_neqn
! systematic computations
  call calc_neqn ( )
end module dimensions
```

I get the following - very clear - error message:

```
Error: Unexpected CALL statement in CONTAINS section at (1)
```

In other words, can a module call a subroutine? And what would be the proper syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules can't execute code *by themselves*.

What you might want to do is something like this:

```
module my_module
    implicit none
    integer :: ndims
    real, dimension(:), allocatable :: my_data
contains
    subroutine initialize()
        ndims = ...
        allocate(my_data(ndims))
    end subroutine initialize
end module my_module

program my_program
    use my_module
    implicit none
    call initialize()
    ....
end program my_program
```

This would give both the `ndim` variable, as well as the `my_data` array to both the module as well as the main program. Just make sure that you don't define either again inside the subroutine, as that would create new variables only inside the scope of `initialize`.

Comment: Your answer is as good as the other. I don't know which one to accept :)

Answer (score 4):

No, the module itself cannot perform any executable code. There are programming languages that allow a default initialization when using a module, but Fortran is not one of them.

You should place your initialization code inside a subroutine and you must remember to call this subroutine from the main program or from some other procedure.

The object oriented approach would be to use an object instead of a module and to have the initialization code in the object initializer procedure.

If your `ndim` was a parameter, you could evaluate the constant precision at compile time. If it is not, you must call `calc_neqn` when you get `ndim` yourself. Then you can allocate your vector (which you do not show) as needed.

Comment: What you state in your 2nd paragraph is precisely what I used to do, but how then can I handle the declaration of the size of my vector ?

Comment: Exactly that way again. There is no vector in your code, so I cannot be more specific.

Comment: I would gladly show my code (or a portion of it) but it is quite large. How can I proceed ?

Comment: "You should place your initialization code inside a subroutine and you must remember to call this subroutine from the main program or from some other procedure." "you must call calc_neqn when you get ndim yourself. Then you can allocate your vector (which you do not show) as needed."

Comment: You must isolate the relevanys part of the code.  Most importantly the definition of the vector. Make sure it is allocatable.

Comment: I'm good now. Thank you for pointing me to the solution and for sharing knowledge.