# Fortran: How to assign values in a module

Tags: list, fortran

I am struggling with a code I got from another person. He uses modules to supply arrays that are needed by the main routine. What I need, is an array with numbers from 500 to 3500.

He did that by writing

```
INTEGER :: i
REAL :: myArray(3001)

DATA (myArray(i),i=1,100)/&
500., 501., 502., 503., [...] 599./

DATA (myArray(i),i=101,200)/&
600., 601., [...], 699./

[...]

DATA (myArray(i),i=2901,3001)/&
[...] 3498., 3499., 3500./
```

Now to me this seems very complicated! Also, I need myArray to contain Integers, but of course I don't want to remove all those dots.

So at first I tried this:

```
Do i=1,3001
    myArray(i) = i+499
End Do
```

But I get

> "error #6274: This statement must not appear in the specification part
>   of a module"

What do I do wrong?

Comment: If you don't want to have explicit initialization (in the sense of "at compile time", so using executable statements) then the answers in [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30073737) apply.  But really, an [array constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/996/arrays/6858/array-constructors#t=201608291552201114144) with implied do to get an explicitly initialized array of that look is no trouble.

Answer (score 3):

You need an implied do loop. This compiles and runs fine

```
MODULE module1

    INTEGER :: i
    REAL :: myArray(3001) = (/ (i, i=500, 3500) /)

END MODULE
```

The format is

```
(/ (exp1, var=start, end) /)
```

or

```
(/ (exp1, var=start, end, step) /)
```

or

```
(/ (exp1, expr2, .., var=start, end, step) /)
```

<sub>See https://web.stanford.edu/class/me200c/tutorial_90/07_arrays.html</sub>

Comment: Worth mentioning that more modern Fortran standards ('03 on if I recall correctly) allow `[` and `]` instead of `(/` and `/)`.

Comment: Thank you. You can tell my archaic style from the all caps keywords. Somewhere near F95 it became standard to use all lowercase and I guess I missed the memo.

Comment: I am trying to find a reference for the different ways to initialize arrays in F03 and later. Its kind of hard to find. Section 3.16 of ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/n1551-n1600/n1579.pdf is the best I could do.

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite explanatory. You can't perform calculations in a module. A module is designed to host variable declarations and subroutine interfaces. You have two options :

- Just declare the type and the dimension of your array in the module and initialize it in your main program (using the module) with the loop you have suggested.
- Or as pointed out by @francescalus, you can directly use an array constructor during the declaration in the module. Something like this : `[(i, i=500, 3500)]`